# Sync folders from different hard drives in google drive windows 10

Tags: sync, google-drive

I have multiple folders and hard drivers (7 hdds)

I would like to use Google Drive to back up my files, however I can only have one folder that I am allowed to syn from.

I have tried `mklink` but it just ignores that folder.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a constraint of Google Drive if you think of your pc as the primary location for files.
From what I've been able to work out, Google Drive seems to think of the Cloud as the centre of the world, not your pc, so therefore your pc would simply be the synchronised backup of the Cloud, not the true master.